# Kendo-combobox issue in mobile

Tags: android, ios, mobile, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I am using Kendo-combobox where i will be able to type and filter the dropdown data. That is  fine in desktop. It looks same in ios mobile as well. but i want it to make as normal select dropdown in ios mobile where dropdown menu pops from the bottom to chose an option. Is there any way to achieve mobile specific dropdown. Please suggest what is the best approach to use kendo combobox in mobile which is user-friendly.Any help is appreciated. Thanks.